# Partial fraction

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> How to expand the following expression
>   $\frac{1}{(x^n-1)(x-1)}$
>   in partial fraction, I think it will be rewritten in terms of geometric series , but how to relate the undefined coefficients with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w_k=e^{2i\pi k/n}$ then the partial fraction has the form:

$$\frac{1}{(x^n-1)(x-1)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{c_k}{x-w_k}+\frac{a}{(x-1)^2}$$

where 
$$c_k=\frac{w_k}{n(w_k-1)}\quad k=1,\ldots,n-1$$
and 
$$\displaystyle a=\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-w_k)}=\frac{1}{n}$$
and with $x=0$ we find 
$$c_0=\frac{1}{n}-1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1-w_k}$$